# Need to parse xmltype values by querying it in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

We have a requirement to capture the values from xmltype column using select statement. Below is the value we have in the column "Test".

```
<c18>A</c18><c18 m="2">B</c18><c18 m="3">C</c18><c18 m="4"D</c18><c18 m="5">E</c18><c18 m="6">F</c18><c18 m="7">G</c18><c18 m="8">H</c18>
```

We need to have 8 new columns which should be named as "C1", "C2", etc having values A,B,C and so on.

Comment: And what is the issue? Apart from well-documented `XMLTABLE` function with lots of various examples in the official docs there are many XML related questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Your XML is invalid (it is missing a closing `>` after `m="4"` and does not have a root element). If you fix that then you can use:

```sql
SELECT x.*
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY XMLTABLE(
         '/root'
         PASSING t.test
         COLUMNS
           c1 VARCHAR2(20) PATH './c18[not(@m)]',
           c2 VARCHAR2(20) PATH './c18[@m="2"]',
           c3 VARCHAR2(20) PATH './c18[@m="3"]',
           c4 VARCHAR2(20) PATH './c18[@m="4"]',
           c5 VARCHAR2(20) PATH './c18[@m="5"]',
           c6 VARCHAR2(20) PATH './c18[@m="6"]',
           c7 VARCHAR2(20) PATH './c18[@m="7"]',
           c8 VARCHAR2(20) PATH './c18[@m="8"]'
       ) x
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (test XMLTYPE);

INSERT INTO table_name (test)
VALUES (XMLTYPE( '<root><c18>A</c18><c18 m="2">B</c18><c18 m="3">C</c18><c18 m="4">D</c18><c18 m="5">E</c18><c18 m="6">F</c18><c18 m="7">G</c18><c18 m="8">H</c18></root>' ) );
```

Outputs:

| C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5 | C6 | C7 | C8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/btLf6OtE)